# MVC 3 Razor and the display of null dates in forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an MVC 3 website where I display dates in forms using:

```
<div class="editor-label control-label">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.rrsfWoman.DateOfBirth)
</div>
<div class="editor-field controls">
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.rrsfWoman.DateOfBirth)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.rrsfWoman.DateOfBirth)
</div>
```

The date of birth is defined in the rrsfWoman class as

```
public DateTime WomansDateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

My problem is that as the date of birth field has by default a value of MinDate. Is there a way I can supress the display of the date as 1/01/0001 *without* making the field nullable.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to make your `WomansDateOfBirth` nullable? This is the proper way of solving your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way I can supress the display of the date as 1/01/0001
>   without making the field nullable.

The correct way to achieve that is to make the date nullable in your view model. If you don't do that later you will struggle with model binding as well because a non-nullable DateTime field cannot be bound to an empty string and you will have to write custom model binders and stuff to make it work. You will make your life miserable if you don't use view models.

This being said, if you want to go against good practices, you could define a custom editor template for the DateTime type that will perform the check and use an empty value but honestly I don't recommend you doing that:

`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml`:

```
@model DateTime

@if (Model == default(DateTime))
{
    @Html.TextBox("", "")
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
}
```

Comment: Thank you - complete and concise response. I will go with best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default value of WomansDateOfBirth explicitly like so:

```
private DateTime _womansDateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime WomansDateOfBirth
{
    get { return _womansDateOfBirth; }
    set { _womansDateOfBirth = value; }
}
```

Where `DateTime.Now` is your MinDate.

Answer (score 0):

If the date field does not allow nulls and you want to force the user to enter a date.
IMO, the best way is to simply clear the input field after the form is built.

So add this little snip-it at the end of your view.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById("DateOfBirth").value = "";
</script>
```